# How can I fix this error: TypeError: cannot unpack non-iterable int object

Tags: python, typeerror

I'm getting **TypeError: cannot unpack non-iterable int object** in the line `S, I, R = y` of the function. I thought saving y as a matrix ([730, 3]) would solve this, it did not.

```
def SIRmodel(y,t):
    S, I, R = y
    return ([-alpha*S*I,alpha*S*I-beta*I,beta*I])
```

I call it below:

```
alpha=mygetrand(cdf,0,0.4,1.e-16) 
beta = 1/11
t = np.linspace(0,730,1001) #two year time period 
pop = 350000000 #population size 
med_capacity = 250000

y=np.array([730,3])
x0=0
x1=0.4

def get_trajectory():
    infec0 = pop*0.00001 #the initial infected
    Iinit = (infec0/pop) #initial infected rate
    Sinit = (pop - infec0)/pop #susceptable population
    Rinit = 0
    sol = rk4sys(SIRmodel,[Sinit,Iinit,Rinit],x0, x1)
    hosp = np.zeros(3) #array of hospitalized
    perc = [0.05, 0.1, 0.2]
    return(sol)

sol = get_trajectory()
plt.plot(t,pop*sol[:,1],'r-',[0,730],[med_capacity,med_capacity],'b:');
#print(pop*soln[:,1])
```

The problem here is at the call `sol = rk4sys(SIRmodel,[Sinit,Iinit,Rinit],x0, x1)`

My rk4 is

```
def rk4sys(f, init, x0, x1):
    h=(x0-x1)/730
    vx = np.zeros(shape=(730,1)) 
    vy = np.zeros(shape=(731,3))

    vx[0] = x = x0 #pythonified assignment statements
    vy[0,:] = y = init
    for i in range(1, 730 + 1):  #runge-kutta loop
        k1 = f(x, y)
        k2 = f(x + 0.5 * h, y + 0.5 * h* k1)
        k3 = f(x + 0.5 * h, y + 0.5 * h* k2)
        k4 = f(x + h, y + h* k3)
        vx[i] = x = x0 + i * h
        vy[i,:] = y = y + h*(k1 + k2 + k2 + k3 + k3 + k4) / 6.
    return vx, vy
```

Comment: You say `x = x0` where `x0 = 0`, and then you call `f(x, y)` which would be `f(0, y)` but 0 is expected to be an iterable object assignable to `S, I, R = 0`. I am not sure what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

Swap the t and y values in the SIRmodel call
`def SIRmodel(t,y):`